awk: try to convert timestamp string to unix epoch time
I try to convert a timestamp string to unix epoch time using awk but fail after several attempts.
$ echo "2024-04-16 16:32:38.108580" | awk '{ epoch = mktime(gensub(/[:-]/, " ", "g", $1)) + substr($1, index($1, ".")+1) ; print epoch }'
2023


mktime() is looking for input of the format YYYY MM DD HH MM SS so in this case we want to:
### convert this:

2024-04-16 16:32:38.108580

### to this:

2024 04 16 16 32 38

We can do this a couple ways:
gensub(/[:-]|[.].*$/, " ", "g")
  gsub(/[:-]|[.].*$/, " ")

Since I don't designate a field or variable to operate on the functions operate on the entire line (ie, $0).
OP's code only performs operations on the first white space delimited field ($1) which in this case is 2024-04-16.  OP will either need to designate the first 2 fields ($1 " " $2) or the whole line ($0 - default behavior if no field designated).
Since the sample input only has the 2 white space delimited fields we'll stick with processing the entire line ($0).
Pulling these changes into a new awk script:
### convert input to mktime() format:

$ echo "2024-04-16 16:32:38.108580" | awk '{ print gensub(/[:-]|[.].*$/, " ", "g") }'
2024 04 16 16 32 38

### convert to epoch seconds:

$ echo "2024-04-16 16:32:38.108580" | awk '{ print mktime(gensub(/[:-]|[.].*$/, " ", "g")) }'
1713303158

### reverse operation to verify we've got the correct epoch seconds

$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d @1713303158
2024-04-16 16:32:38


If we need to append the .108580 on the end we can re-use OP's substr( index() ) code as long as we remember to operate on the entire line ($0):
$ echo "2024-04-16 16:32:38.108580" | awk '{ print mktime(gensub(/[:-]|[.].*$/, " ", "g")) substr($0, index($0, ".")) }'
1713303158.108580


The same as above, TZ isn't taken into account and displays it with your local TZ offset

".... displays it with your local TZ offset" . Seems like a feature. What do you think?

@shelter I think it can lead to misinterpretation at data exchange for example in software like calendars and so on. As you can spot it out even here there's two different results of interpretation of the same data in two aswers above. Suppose it's not critical here but anyway it's good to note.

You are operating on $1 but should be operating on $0. You would have seen this if you had examined the intermediate steps of your command.
You also have an off-by-one error.
This should work:
$ echo "2024-04-16 16:32:38.108580" |
  awk '{
    i = index($0, ".")
    datespec = gensub(/[:-]/, " ", "g", substr($0,1,i-1))
    epoch = mktime(datespec) + substr($0,i)
    printf "%f\n", epoch
  }'
1713281558.108580
$

In fact, just changing $0 to $1 and fixing the off-by-one error in your original works even with the fraction left in but I don't know if this behaviour is guaranteed:
$ echo "2024-04-16 16:32:38.108580" |
  awk '{
    epoch = mktime(gensub(/[:-]/, " ", "g", $0)) + substr($0, index($0, "."))
    printf "%f\n", epoch
  }'
1713281558.108580
$


for a one-off standalone conversion, with GNU date: date +%s.%6N -d "2024-04-16 16:32:38.108580"

to get epoch as a string (that looks like a floating point) rather than an actual floating point, just leave out the +

Taking into account TZ: printf "%.6f\n" $(date '+%s.%N' -d "2024-04-16 16:32:38.108580") and awk version can show different results

@yvs2014 Can you provide an example? When I set TZ before running, I get the same output from date as I do from gawk. I could, however, see getting different results if the input string included an explicit TZ

"I could, however, see getting different results if the input string included an explicit TZ" -- it is kinda slip-up in data interpretation, if TZ is unspecified I'd assume it's UTC+0

@yvs2014 for me, if unspecified, I would assume the TZ of the processor. Consider: When I say "my meeting will be at 7pm", the common assumption is that I mean 7pm in my timezone, unless I specify explicitly, not that I mean 7pm UTC even though my TZ is UTC+9. However, I don't disagree that there is an ambiguity (which is best avoided by being explicit)

it's a good common assumption, if (and only if) a correspondent (human or machine) knows "my timezone". Otherwise there will be misinterpration. "which is best avoided by being explicit" -- you can say that again

You could also use the function strptime which is part of Gnu awk's time-extension. strptime sadly does not recognizes fractional seconds, but it is a nice way to bypass the substitution magic:
awk '@load "time"; BEGIN{dstr="2024-04-16 16:32:38.108580"; print strptime(dstr,"%F %T")+substr(dstr,index(dstr,"."))}'

